# Comparing Biased Random Walk models

Tags: probability-theory, random-walk, random-matrices

Given a single graph, and two different **"biased" random walk models** on the same undirected graph, how does on **theoretically** **compare** the two models? What are the metrics one should theoretically study to show one method's superiority over the other? For e.g., is "mixing time" a good performance metric to compare on?

Comment: When is a random walk better than another? What are you trying to accomplish with it?

Comment: @parsiad As in which walk is faster or which walk covers more of the nodes from a particular subgraph?